# How I undo my last commit?

Tags: git, undo, git-commit

I accidentally rest my commit  in git and I would undo the last commit are their any way to undo last commit in git .

- I want to undo the last rest .

Comment: seriously, do search before posting - the question is a dupe of one with 2700+ upvotes!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~
```

This will not remove new files or changes in the files.  It only reverts the commit so the commit never happened.  If you want the changes not to be in the files use `--hard` instead of `--soft`.

Answer (score -1):

Simply reset the branch to the previous commit, if everything has been done locally.